# Java How to identify which values of an Array of Strings are not present in a List of Objects?

Tags: java

Which is the most efficient way to achieve the following?

Having a List of Strings and a List of Objects :

```
  List<String> arrayStrings=Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3","4");
  List<MyCustomDTO> dtoList=new ArrayList();

  MyCustomDTO myFirstDTO=new MyCustomDTO("1");
  MyCustomDTO mySecondDTO=new MyCustomDTO("2");

  dtoList.add(myFirstDTO);
  dtoList.add(mySecondDTO);
```

Where MyCustomDTO only has the following:

```
public class MyCustomDTO {
private String code;

public MyCustomDTO(String code) {
    this.code=code;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
```

}

I need to iterate *dtoList* and check which values from arrayStrings are not present in it comparing to the **Code** field
In that example the correct output would be ["3","4"] ,because the only 2 elements inside dtoList ,have the code "1" and "2" ,that appears in the *arrayStrings* .
I know there are a couple of ways,but i am looking for the most efficient way to do this,because i could have a lot of elements inside both list.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show us at least one way how you would solve this, at least some effort.

Comment: How many elements do you expect in those lists? How much is "a lot" for you?

Comment: Probably no more than 100

Comment: Thats a few elements and performance doesn't matter. "a lot" = millions of elements. You can  use the first method you can think of and won't see any performance issues.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If expected number of elements in dtoList is big (let's say > 10_000) you should first create set of all DTO's codes and then filter arrayStrings using this set:

```
Set<String> dtoCodes = dtoList.stream().map(d -> d.getCode()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<String> result = arrayStrings.stream().filter(s -> !dtoCodes.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However if expected cardinality of dtoList is small , you should go the most straightforward way without bothering CPU performance optimization.

Also note that cardinality of arrayStrings doesn't matter in that case.